# Why this Typerror : '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'FirefoxWebElement'?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to code a script using Python and Selenium, to compare the numbers between `value _metal`, `value_crystal` and `value_deut` with  `gauss_met_req`, `gauss_crys_req`, and `gauss_deut_req`.

This error keeps popping up

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/badjorans/Desktop/stob/selenss.py", line 138, in `<module>`
>       if value_crystal > gauss_crys_req and value_metal > gauss_met_req  and value_deuterium > gauss_deut_req :
>   TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'FirefoxWebElement'

I tried to convert the numbers to float but the error keeps appearing.

```py
metal = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/span")
crystal = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/span")
deuterium = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[3]/span")
blackmatter = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a/span")
energy = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[4]/span")

value_metal = float(metal.text)
value_deuterium = float(deuterium.text)
value_crystal = float(crystal.text)
value_energy = int(energy.text)

gauss_met_req = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[2]")
print (gauss_met_req.text)
value_gauss_met = float(gauss_met_req.text)

gauss_crys_req = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div[2]")
print (gauss_crys_req.text)
value_gauss_crys = float(gauss_crys_req.text)

gauss_deut_req = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/div[2]")
print (gauss_deut_req.text)
value_gauss_deut = float(gauss_deut_req.text)


print(value_metal)
print (value_crystal)
print(value_deuterium)

if value_crystal > gauss_crys_req and value_metal > gauss_met_req  and value_deuterium > gauss_deut_req :
    print ("we have enough resources to build Gauss Canon")

else:
    print ("NOT ENOUGH RESOURCES")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't convert `gauss_crys_req`, `gauss_met_req`, and `gauss_deut_req` to floats like you did with `value_crystal`, `value_metal`, and `value_deuterium`. You seem to already know how to get the text from an element and convert it to a float, so just use the same method for all the variables you are comparing in your conditional.

Comment: thank you so much...this was lack of atention. too tired i guess.it worked :)

Comment: If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.